# How to run ansible task with multiple array variables?

Tags: arrays, ansible, devops

There is host_vars/my_host.yml file which include array variables:

```
---
my_array_variable_1: '"arr1_el1" "arr1_el2"'
my_array_variable_2: '"arr2_el1" 
my_array_variable_3: '"file1" "file2"'
```

There is task main.yml that doesn't work as I suppose:

---

```
- name: my task.
  shell: |
    echo "{{ my_array_variable_1[] }} {{ my_array_variable_2[] }}" >>/home/user/{{ my_array_variable_3[] }}
```

1) How can I get this result:

```
# cat /home/user/file1
arr1_el1
arr2_el1
# cat /home/user/file2
arr1_el2
arr2_el1
```

2) How can I get this result:

```
# cat /home/user/file1
arr1_el1
arr1_el2
arr2_el1
# cat /home/user/file2
arr1_el1
arr1_el2
arr2_el1
```

3) How can I get this result:

```
# cat /home/user/file1
arr1_el1
arr2_el1
# cat /home/user/file2
arr1_el2
```

I'm searching, but can't find clear example neither ansible official docs nor via search engines.
Please help with result or get url to revelant documentation or example.

Regards

**UPD:** Find that I need to use dictionary and "with_dict" to create Associative array like [this](http://%20https://serverfault.com/questions/632868/associative-array-in-ansible-playbook) 
How should I write task to get all elements like at mine result 2 or particular values like at result 3

**UPD2:** I've found [example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-dict) at ansible docs how to work with dicts but how to include it to host_vars file? I get the error below:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'dict'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use [dict module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-dict). This allows forming arrays of any complexity through dictionaries.

Comment: Please, fix the link.

Comment: sorry for delay)